# What is a Material Called that Translates the Image of a Touching Object's Surface?

Tags: optics, visible-light, material-science, optical-materials, metamaterials

What is the name of a material that moves light through it in such a way that it appears that the surface of an object has translated through the material? Also, what is an example of this type of material?

[image: image that shows an example of normal transparency and the type of surface translation I'm looking for]

From very distant memory, I think this does not occur in nature, but is a metamaterial that can be created by binding fiber optic fibers together. But I cannot find a reference or a material on the market.

Comment: An additional content for background:  My 8th grade science teacher gave us a hunk of quartz and a hunk of something else. This was back in the 90s and fiber optics were incredibly rare. But I think I remember him stating that this was a characteristic of bundled fiber optics.

Comment: Like this? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ulexite

Comment: Yes. That's exactly what we had in 8th grade science class. Ulexite. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ulexite:

The light transmits.

An example found in nature is Ulexite.